# Do sorting algorithms show more unstability when dealing with an array of composite data types?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Or is the stability the same as when dealing with an array of primitive data types?

Comment: I think the answer is no, but can you give a specific example?

Comment: What do you mean by unstability?

Comment: This is more of a theoretical problem. You should go ahead and ask on [https://cs.stackexchange.com/](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The concept of stability doesn't apply when dealing with primitive types - [1,1,2,3,4] is the same as [1,1,2,3,4].

Comment: @dukeling: -0.0 == 0.0, assuming  you consider `double` a primitive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sorting an array of primitive values by their actual full values, the notion of stability is not really relevant.

If you have an array **[2,1,3,2]** and you sort it then you get **[1,2,2,3]**.  The result is exactly the same whether you use a stable or unstable sort.

When you are not sorting by the full value, i.e., when items that compare equal are actually different, *then* stability becomes relevant.  For instance, if you sort an array of integers by the sum of their digits, then **[11,5,13,22]** will become **[11,13,22,5]** with a stable sort, but an unstable sort *may* give you **[11,22,13,5]**.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting boils down to comparing two items. So, as long as the items are comparable in a way that results in 'less', 'egal', 'greater', the sorting algorithms will work fine.

E.g. in Java, your class can implement the Comparable interface's compareTo() method, and this it the used by e.g. Collections.sort().

To make the sorting stable, you will need to take all fields of the items into account when performing the comparison.

Comment: Your answer only applies to correctness not to [stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).The sorting may be correct, but that does not necessarily mean that equal elements appear in the same order as they were given in the input.

Comment: @FK82 I guess it depends on how you implement the comparison. If it does not take into account all data of the items, the sorting may becomde unstable.

Comment: Exactly, you should add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the possibility that the question is about stability and sorting primitives versus objects, then in the case of some compiler languages, a variation of quick sort is used on primitives, which is not stable, while a variation of merge sort is used on objects which is stable. This is because stability normally isn't an issue if sorting primitives.

One way to detect stability with a primitive integer type is to use part of the integer as an original sequence value, and using a custom compare that only compares the other part. Perhaps for 32 bit integers, the upper 16 bits filled with random data and used for compare, the lower 16 bits used as original sequence indicator.